# How do secure a radiator to a wall, after it was already been poorly fitted

Tags: radiator

Have a radiator handing off the wall, its essentially stay in position because of its own weight.

The wall behind it is plaster board over brick.

As you can see the screws and plugs have completely come out and the holes are way bigger than the screws.

Any tips on resolving this, considering the holes are already there.

[image: radiator]

[image: radiator]

[image: radiator]

Comment: btw, what's holding that radiator on is mainly now the pipes, so you don't want to wait too long to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the radiator, fill the holes & start over.
Those existing plugs are plasterboard plugs, but as you have brick behind, you can use regular 'rawlplugs' [generic 'brown plugs'] when re-fitting. You want to be properly fixing into the brick, not plasterboard &/or air gap.

Fill with something cement-based. Exterior Polyfilla or equivalent, which will be hard enough when cured to drill properly & be able to take regular plugs. If you can find something like that in a gun, it will make filling right to the back of the existing holes easier.

Don't put those toy screws back. If you're serious, then use at least 4" No8 or 6" No10 [100 - 150mm in new money] & no-one will ever pull them off. That will mean drilling 4-6"  into the wall [borrow an SDS if you can get one, domestic hammer drills & brickwork are not great partners, you end up with conical holes rather than parallel sided], then sending two plugs in, one behind the other.

Answer (score 0):

Those anchors that were used seem to be made for drywall to hold light pieces, small pictures, not heavy objects.

If you are lucky, will have wood studs holding the drywall and can use the studs with screws to hold the radiator.  If no studs, just brick behind the drywall, will need brick anchors into the brick to use.